# Does a bitcoin pool appear as one node or multiple nodes to the rest of the network?

Tags: mining-pools, network, nodes

I'm guessing that it appears as a single node?  For example on http://getaddr.bitnodes.io/?

Answer (score 1):

The pool will typically appear as one node, though there's nothing stopping a business entity identifying as a pool to operate several nodes.

In any case, the miners in the pool will certainly not appear as nodes.